# Why doesn't react component render when trying to render it in another components click function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render buttons to a page which when clicked render the hard-coded weather data to the page depending on the day that was clicked. The click function works fine and the buttons are rendered just as I expect them to, but when a button is clicked the `Day` component doesn't render.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong since my code reaches the `console.log` in the click handler function. Then the handler function should render the component but for some reason it does not.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import myData from "./weather.json";

class Day extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      description: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log("at last"); //this isn't reached
    return (
      <div className="dayWeather">
        <div className="dayWeather">Humidity {this.props.humidity}</div>
        <div className="dayWeather">Temperature {this.props.temperature}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class DayRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      days: Array(7).fill(null)
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.renderDay = this.renderDay.bind(this);
  }

  handler(day) {
    let daysWeather = myData[day];
    console.log("now we've reached this far"); //this console log is reached when a button is clicked.
    return (
      <Day
        humidity={daysWeather.humidity}
        temperature={daysWeather.temperature}
      />
    );
  }

  renderDay(day) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className="day"
          onClick={() => {
            this.handler(day);
          }}
        >
          {day}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="day-row">
          {this.renderDay("Monday")}
          {this.renderDay("Tuesday")}
          {this.renderDay("Wednesday")}
          {this.renderDay("Thursday")}
          {this.renderDay("Friday")}
          {this.renderDay("Saturday")}
          {this.renderDay("Sunday")}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Weather extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="weather">
        <div className="weather-panel">
          <DayRow />
        </div>
        <div className="day" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(<Weather />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Where do you want it to render? Currently, you're just invoking the `handler` function, but you never use the rendered result anywhere. The correct way is to set compoment state from the click handler, then use the state to determine what to render.

Comment: Do i need to reserve space for the rendered `day` component in the `DayRow` components render function? I am just trying to get some data to the page so that I can position it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't return UI elements in click handler as it won't render. Just set a flag inside handler and use it to display the `Day` component inside your render function.

```
class DayRow extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    days: Array(7).fill(null),
    showDay: false
  };
  this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  this.renderDay = this.renderDay.bind(this);
}

handler() {
  this.setState({
    showDay: true,
  });
}

renderDayComponent(day) {
  let daysWeather = myData[day];
  console.log("now we've reached this far"); //this console log is reached when a button is clicked.
  return (
    <Day
      humidity={daysWeather.humidity}
      temperature={daysWeather.temperature}
    />
  );
}

renderDay(day) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="day"
        onClick={() => {
          this.handler();
        }}
      >
        {day}
      </button>
      {this.state.showDay && this.renderDayComponent(day)}
    </div>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="day-row">
        {this.renderDay("Monday")}
        {this.renderDay("Tuesday")}
        {this.renderDay("Wednesday")}
        {this.renderDay("Thursday")}
        {this.renderDay("Friday")}
        {this.renderDay("Saturday")}
        {this.renderDay("Sunday")}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to render the day in the `Weather` compoment? To do this, you must keep some sort of `state` so that React knows what to render. Whenever you change the state, React will call `render` to re-render your compoment.

Therefore, since the state of wether or not a day is to be shown is local to the Weather component, you need to store the state there:

```
class Weather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)
    this.state = { activeDay: undefined }
  }

  render() {
    // Store the current dayData in a variable if an activeDay is chosen, it will be falsy if no day has been chosen.
    const dayData = this.state.activeDay && myData[this.state.activeDay]
    return (
      <div className="weather">
        <div className="weather-panel">
          // DayRow will inform Weather when a day has been selected, i.e., clicked
          <DayRow onSelected={day => this.setState({ activeDay: day })} />
        </div>
        <div className="day">
          // This is where you are rendering the day, only if a day
          // is active. I.e., dayData is truthy
          { dayData && <Day humitidy={dayData.humitidy} temperature={dayData.temperature} /> }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Your `DayRow` would simple communicate with `Weather` by saying which day is selected.

```
class DayRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderDay = this.renderDay.bind(this)
  }

  renderDay(day) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className="day"
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.onSelected(day);
          }}
        >
          {day}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="day-row">
          {this.renderDay("Monday")}
          {this.renderDay("Tuesday")}
          {this.renderDay("Wednesday")}
          {this.renderDay("Thursday")}
          {this.renderDay("Friday")}
          {this.renderDay("Saturday")}
          {this.renderDay("Sunday")}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning JSX from your event handler will not render it. You have to do all rendering in your component's render method.

You could instead have an additional object in your `state` that keep track of if the `day` has been clicked or not, and use that `state` in your rendering.

```
class DayRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      days: Array(7).fill(null),
      showDays: {}
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.renderDay = this.renderDay.bind(this);
  }

  handler(day) {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const showDays = { ...previousState.showDays };
      showDays[day] = !showDays[day];
      return { showDays };
    });
  }

  renderDay(day) {
    let daysWeather = myData[day];
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className="day"
          onClick={() => {
            this.handler(day);
          }}
        >
          {day}
        </button>
        {this.state.showDays[day] && (
          <Day
            humidity={daysWeather.humidity}
            temperature={daysWeather.temperature}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned  component from handler function is being passed to onClick event. Its not getting into the DOM tree.

You can change the code as shown below.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import myData from './weather.json';

const myData = 
class Day extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      description: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log('at last'); //this isn't reached
    return (
      <div className="dayWeather">
        <div className="dayWeather">Humidity {this.props.humidity}</div>
        <div className="dayWeather">Temperature {this.props.temperature}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class DayRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      days: Array(7).fill(null)
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.renderDay = this.renderDay.bind(this);
  }

  handler(day) {
    let daysWeather = myData[day];
    console.log('now we\'ve reached this far'); //this console log is reached when a button is clicked.
    this.props.handler(daysWeather);
  }

  renderDay(day) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className="day"
          onClick={() => {
            this.handler(day);
          }}
        >
          {day}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="day-row">
          {this.renderDay('Monday')}
          {this.renderDay('Tuesday')}
          {this.renderDay('Wednesday')}
          {this.renderDay('Thursday')}
          {this.renderDay('Friday')}
          {this.renderDay('Saturday')}
          {this.renderDay('Sunday')}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Weather extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedDay: {}
        };
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    }

    handler(day){
        this.setState({
            selectedDay: day
        });
    }
  render() {

    let day = null;
    if(Object.keys(this.state.selectedDay) > 0){
        day = <Day
            humidity={selectedDay.humidity}
            temperature={selectedDay.temperature}
        />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="weather">
        <div className="weather-panel">
          <DayRow onDayChange={this.handler}/>
        </div>
        <div className="day">
            {day}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(<Weather />, document.getElementById('root'));
```